# This C program is not executing

Tags: c

I have this simple C program, It compiles successfully but It does not execute perfectly. It takes the input and closed after a while. I don't know, why it is not displaying output?
Please help me...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void main()
{
    char str1[200], str2[200];
    
    system("cls");
    
    printf("<==== Enter two strings ====>\n");
    printf("First: ");
    scanf("%s", &str1);
    printf("Second: ");
    scanf("%s", &str2);

    char txt1[] = "\nThe string \" ";
    char txt2[] = " \"and \"";
    char txt3[] = " not equal.";

   
    strcat(strcat(strcat(strcat(txt1, str1), txt2), str2), txt3); 

    if(strcmp(str1, str2) != 0)
    {   
        printf("%s", txt2);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nString 1 and string 2 are equal.");
    }   
    
    getch();  
}
```

Comment: ```void main()```?

Comment: If you want to input a string, you need to delete ```&```. Like ```scanf("%s", str1);```

Answer (score 1):

- Passing pointers to arrays to `scanf()` invokes *undefined behavior* because it is not it excepts. `&` should be removed and pointers to `char` should be passed. Using `%d` with `char*` also invokes *undefined behavior*. `int*` should be passed for that.
- `txt1` has no room for extra things, so the `strcat()` will cause out-of-range access, which also invokes *undefined behavior*. You should specify the number of elements explicitly to allocate enough elements.
- (optional) You should specify the maximum length to read in `%s` for avoiding buffer overrun.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void main()
{
    char str1[200], str2[200];
    
    system("cls");
    
    printf("<==== Enter two strings ====>\n");
    printf("First: ");
    scanf("%199s", str1); /* remove & and add length limit */
    printf("Second: ");
    scanf("%199s", str2); /* remove & and use correct specifier */

    char txt1[512] = "\nThe string \" "; /* allocate enough elements */
    char txt2[] = " \"and \"";
    char txt3[] = " not equal.";

   
    strcat(strcat(strcat(strcat(txt1, str1), txt2), str2), txt3); 

    if(strcmp(str1, str2) != 0)
    {   
        printf("%s", txt2);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nString 1 and string 2 are equal.");
    }   
    
    getch();  
}
```